# How to efficiently read large sas data sets

Tags: sas

I have a sas data set that is about 8 gigabytes. I was wondering if there is an easy way I can read this data set in in the data step. It takes about 2 hours for the data step to complete.

Comment: Define 'efficient' for your use. Do you want to optimize on speed, minimal memory usage, minimal cpu usage, minimal disk/network IO, etc.?

Comment: I want the data step to complete in under 10 minutes. I would ideally like to compress the dataset. I am testing a program so I will have to reread the data multiple times. Also when scrolling through large data sets, there is lag.

Comment: Can you link to a definition of 'sas data'? Also, do you have the option of pre-processing data before it reaches your software (splitting, parsing, etc)? Do you read the data from network or from disk? And have you profiled your software to determine where the bottleneck is?

Comment: can you give us an example of what your code is doing?  It's hard to make suggestions without an idea of what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Specific times and performance will depend on your hardware.  However, some tips.

- `options compress=yes;` will compress the dataset, saving potentially large amounts of space (depending on the data).  `options compress=char;` is another option appropriate when character data is the majority of the space used.
- Limit the number of times you read through the data.  Write your program such that it doesn't need as many data passes.  Consider using views, and when combining datasets using techniques like format or hash instead of sorting and joining.
- Use `PROC PRINT` to view the data rather than browsing the dataset, as you can customize the results more effectively.
- If you are on a server consider the `SPDE` engine.  That allows you to spread the data across multiple disks.

Comment: All good tips.  It's also worth noting that the biggest advantage likely to be gained is by compressing both the input AND output datasets.  This will reduce the disk I/O associated with reading the data in and writing it back to disk - the slowest processes involved in this.  Also be sure you have plenty of free space on the drive you are writing to.  If you don't want to use the compress options you can also make sure that you have appropriate column widths - this will have an impact similar to compressing the data.

Comment: For most uses, `options compress=yes;` should be the default setting for the system unless it has enough RAM to store all data used in a session - it almost always helps, at least a little bit, unless you're doing something heavily CPU constrained.  CPUs are so fast compared to storage nowadays that you won't find the CPU overhead of compress to cost you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Joe's answer and the other comments so far answer the question directly - they do a good job of covering ways of increasing read speeds. However, I think it's also worth mentioning a few potential means of cutting down the number of records that *actually need to be read*, as this will also speed up each pass.

This is necessarily quite a speculative answer, but depending on what your code's doing, some of these might be worth investigating further.

**Indexes**

If you only want to process a relatively small proportion of records (< 20%) in each pass through your dataset, using a series of similar and reasonably simple where clauses in successive passes, you could consider creating indexes for the some of the variables in the where clauses. The smaller the proportion of records you are interested in, the greater the benefit will be from using indexes, as they will allow SAS to skip reading large sections of your dataset.

There is a one-off initial processing overhead when creating an index, and a further cost each time you alter the dataset. The index will also occupy some additional disk space.

**Obs and firstobs**

If you're only interested in observations in a particular position within your dataset (e.g. from observation 10000 to observation 20000 inclusive), you can skip straight to those ones and ignore all the others via the obs= and firstobs= options (in this case, via obs = 20000 and firstobs = 10000).

**Sortedby**

If the dataset happens to be sorted by a variable used in a where clause, you can also use the sortedby= option on a set statement to speed up where clause processing.